# Add a string to the end of hash values

Tags: perl

I'm new in perl and have a question concerning the use of hashes. Althought similar questions were posted before none of them was related to my problem.

I have a fasta file with several sequences of different length and want to add a string (N in this case) to the end of each fasta entry until the length of all sequences are the same. At this point I'm being able to read the fasta file and return each sequence as a string (but can also be done as arrays) to the value of an hash. The key elements are the corresponding headers of the fasta file.

My code is the following:

```
###### calculate the length of each hash value and store the highest value in $max
my $length;
my $max = 0;
my $addN = "N";

foreach $name ( keys %seq ) {
    $length = length($seq{$name});
    if ($max < $length) {
        $max = $length;
    } else { next }
    print $max,"\n";

    while (length ($seq{$name}) < $max) {
        $seq{$name} .= $addN;
    }
    foreach $name (keys %seq) {
        print $seq{$name};
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the output of this code is exactly the same as the input, e.g.,

```
INPUT:
>fasta1
AAAAAAAAA
>fasta2
AA
OUTPUT
>fasta1
AAAAAAAAA
>fasta2
AA
```

where I wanted an output like this:

```
>fasta1
AAAAAAAAA
>fasta2
AANNNNNNN
```

Can you please help me to accomplish this task?

Comment: Your code looks plain wrong after reformatting it. Did you make simplifications before posting it that results in this incorrect nesting?

Comment: It's not obvious to me how the sample input is read in - presume it goes in to the %seq hash somehow?  Might help if you could explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use 5.014;
my %seq = ( fasta1 => 'AAA',
            fasta2 => 'AAAAAA',
            fasta3 => 'AAAAAAAAA',
          );

my $length = length((sort { length($a) < length($b) } values %seq)[0]);
for my $name ( keys %seq ) {
    $seq{$name} = $seq{$name} . ('N' x ($length - length($seq{$name})));
}

while (my($name, $val) = each %seq ) {
    say "$name: $val";
}

fasta2: AAAAAANNN
fasta3: AAAAAAAAA
fasta1: AAANNNNNN
```

Comment: Hello community, many thanks to Oesor and Sebastian, both your codes work just fine to me. Now I can move on! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is wrong. However, it sounds like you have a way to populate a map based on a "fasta" file. Assuming this is true, I think the following code solves your problem.

```
# Populate %seq from fasta file
%seq = (                                                         
    "fasta1"=> "AAAAAAAAA",                                      
    "fasta2" => "AAAA",                                          
    "fasta3" => "AA"                                             
);                                                               

my $FILL = "N";                                                  
my $normalized_length = 0;                                       

# If the normalized length = longest value                       
while( my ($k,$v) = each %seq) {                                 
    my $len = length($v);                                        
    $normalized_length = $len if $len > $normalized_length;      
}                                                                

while( my ($k,$v) = each %seq) {                                 
    print $v, $FILL x ($normalized_length - length($v)), "\n";   
}
```

OUTPUT

```
AAAANNNNN
AANNNNNNN
AAAAAAAAA
```

If you need to normalize to a fixed length, then just set $normalized_length to that value and skip the first while loop.

Comment: Hello community, many thanks to Oesor and Sebastian, both your codes work just fine to me. Now I can move on! Cheers